# how to use a variable inside assertExists

Tags: javascript, testing, casperjs

Is there a way to use a variable's value inside `assertExists`'s first parameter, which is a `String`?
So I need something like:

```
test.assertExists('a[href=nameOfVariable]', 'Link found');
```

where `nameOfVariable` is my variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a common understanding, consider the code below as our reference:

```
//value is "value" :: name is "nameOfVariable"
var nameOfVariable = "value";
```

Now going back to your question,`name` of the variable or the `value` of the variable?
If it's the latter, then you can just append it: `test.assertExists('a[href="' + nameOfVariable + '"]', 'Link found');`

But if you want to get the name, you can use a hash table:

```
var obj = { nameOfVariable: "value" };
for(var k in obj)
    alert(k); //alerts the "nameOfVariable"
```

Comment: I needed a value of variable. The answer works. Thanks!